# Hydro: Getting blank (black) screen in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am getting a random blank (black) screen in Gazebo 1.9 under VMWare running ROS Hydro. I have run groovy and other releases and did not have this issue until hydro. Has anyone else running hydro with Gazebo 1.9 under VMWare experienced this problem. Or any insights as to how to investigate this other then going to a duel boot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4088/hydro:-getting-blank-(black)-screen-in-gazebo/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This issue is related to VM I am using VMWare and when I turn off 3D acceleration in the VM the blank screen issue goes away.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) with karma: 107 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gknight](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/463/gknight/) on 2013-08-15**:
This fixed my issue as well turn off 3d acceleration. Thanks.

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2882/bergercookie/) on 2016-10-27**:
Indeed, nice debugging on this! Encountered the same problem when running gazebo5. Seriously though, just a black screen without any debugging/warning messages is not  the best way to go